# Is defining a Expired computed-column a good idea?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, calculated-columns

In my table, I got a **Expiration_Date** column with a *date* data-type and I was wondering if defining a **Expired** column with this formula is a good idea.

> (CONVERT([bit],case when [Expiration_Date] < getdate() then (1) else (0) end,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?

It would only be a convenience though as it wouldn't allow you to persist or index this column anyway (because of the dependence on `getdate()`)

Also you shouldn't use it in a `WHERE` clause as it is not sargable. If you wanted to find expired users a query on `[Expiration_Date] < getdate()` would be better.

Comment: Well, if it's not a good idea to use it in a WHERE clause, it's become pretty useless.